# Symfony 3.4 service

Tags: php, symfony

**How to call symfony service in custom php file?**
*Service already created in bundle.
This php script will run from command line. Please help.*

Comment: Are you able to use a symfony console command? If so you are set with all Symfony services available https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console.html

Comment: What do you mean by a custom php file? Why don't you use a Symfony console command with ContainerAwareInterface?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Comment: It's working, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom php file as you described is not a good practice, typically services are called from a Controller.

If you need to run some code from the command line, you can use the Symfony Console Commands, that allows you to execute asynchronous tasks with Crons, for example.

As described in Symfony docs, you can pass as many service that you need passing it to the command constructor, here you can find a basic example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use App\Service\UserManager;

class CreateUserCommand extends Command
{
     private $userManager;

public function __construct(UserManager $userManager)
{
    $this->userManager = $userManager;

    parent::__construct();
}

// ...

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    // ...

    $this->userManager->create($input->getArgument('username'));

    $output->writeln('User successfully generated!');
}
}
```

Please, take a look into this link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Hope this help!